# How do I change Firefox's default language?

Tags: 11.10, firefox

I need to change Firefox's default language to Spanish (it's set to English right now), but have been unable to find a solution so far. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first step would be to install `firefox-locale-es` package:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox-locale-es
```

then choose Language suppport and then choose spanish. Start firefox and firefox will have spanish.

Comment: Might want to elaborate on the "Language support" part. I have the locale installed but can't find anywhere to enable it. The stragest thing is that on Windows Firefox is completely translated and on Ubuntu only several strings are in finnish.

Comment: _then choose Language suppport_ I skiped this step (just Firefox reboot).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Firefox language on preferences, on the tab content, there is an option called language or something like that.